# Unable to setup memSQL error logs

Tags: singlestore

im testing memsql for speed so i am using mariadb async DB client for memsql
im using about 100  similar tables with OrderID as primary key
im  often getting this error below on my console

Leaf Error (94.130.55.215:3308): Duplicate entry '71862' for key 'PRIMARY'

I understand this is key violation but is hard for me to debug the problem as table name is not in error

after hitting manual i am able to setup query log but error log i am unable to setup, I think error log will also show the same info

My request to MemSQL team is to add table name to the error message...
and please suggest me the global variable to enable error log

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug the issue, the recommended approach is to instrument your application such that when it receives that error it prints the corresponding query to your application log.  MemSQL follows MySQL error message formatting which tends to lean towards providing the minimum possible context in error messages (since the application has the remainder of the context).

The only query level log we support is the general_log.  For reference you run `SET GLOBAL general_log = ON` to turn it on, and `= OFF` to disable.  The query log does not contain errors or query results, it only lists the queries run against the node on which it is running.